# COM - Access is denied

Tags: c#, com, dcom, opc

I have been stuck now for about 5 days with this problem now.

Basically I'm trying to connect to an OPC server (Kepware) from a remote pc. The code I have written works if I run it on the server where Kepware is installed (in this example 192.168.102.104).

However if I run it from a remote PC I get the following error.

```
System.UnauthorizedAccesException: Access is denied 
(Error from HRESULT: 0x080070005 E_ACCESSIFDENIED))
```

I have setup the server following these instructions:
http://www.kepware.com/Support_Center/SupportDocuments/Remote%20OPC%20DA%20-%20Quick%20Start%20Guide%20(DCOM).pdf

The PCs are not in a domain and both PCs contain the user Administrator with the same password.

Could anyone tell me if the problem might be with the PCs setup or my Code

CODE::

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Unmanaged.CoInitializeSecurity(IntPtr.Zero, -1, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero,
                                           Unmanaged.RpcAuthnLevel.Connect,
                                           Unmanaged.RpcImpLevel.Anonymous, IntPtr.Zero,
                                           Unmanaged.EoAuthnCap.None, IntPtr.Zero);

            using (new Impersonation("Administrator", "TEST", "Password"))
            {
                OPCServer opcServer = new OPCServer();
                opcServer.Connect("Kepware.KEPServerEx.V5", "192.168.102.104");
                Console.WriteLine(opcServer.ServerName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection error:::\n\n{0}\n\n",ex);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Unmanaged Class::

```
partial class Unmanaged
{
    [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    public static extern int CoInitializeSecurity(IntPtr pVoid, int
        cAuthSvc, IntPtr asAuthSvc, IntPtr pReserved1, RpcAuthnLevel level,
        RpcImpLevel impers, IntPtr pAuthList, EoAuthnCap dwCapabilities, IntPtr
        pReserved3);

    public enum RpcAuthnLevel
    {
        Default = 0,
        None = 1,
        Connect = 2,
        Call = 3,
        Pkt = 4,
        PktIntegrity = 5,
        PktPrivacy = 6
    }

    public enum RpcImpLevel
    {
        Default = 0,
        Anonymous = 1,
        Identify = 2,
        Impersonate = 3,
        Delegate = 4
    }

    public enum EoAuthnCap
    {
        None = 0x00,
        MutualAuth = 0x01,
        StaticCloaking = 0x20,
        DynamicCloaking = 0x40,
        AnyAuthority = 0x80,
        MakeFullSIC = 0x100,
        Default = 0x800,
        SecureRefs = 0x02,
        AccessControl = 0x04,
        AppID = 0x08,
        Dynamic = 0x10,
        RequireFullSIC = 0x200,
        AutoImpersonate = 0x400,
        NoCustomMarshal = 0x2000,
        DisableAAA = 0x1000
    }
}
```

The impersonation class just impersonates the local user Administrator.

When I run this on the server with Kepware I get the output - Kepware.KepServerEx.V5
When I run it on the client PC I get the above error

Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are on the wrong end of the wire.  You cannot impersonate a user account that's only know on by that machine, that the user name matches doesn't matter.  You'll have to go through the DCOM config hoopla on the remote machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the source of the problem.

Why is it always the way that as soon as I post I figure it out?

The problem was with how the server was set up. I won't bore you with all the details here but it was to do with the identity in the DCOM settings (in DCONcnfg) being set to the wrong user.

Apparently I ignored that bit of the server set up instructions.

Sorry for wasting anyone's time.